# PostgreSQL: SELECT WHERE less than 15 minutes old

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, timestamp

From the `events` table below, how do I select `events` created less than 15 minutes ago?

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 88):

```
SELECT created_at FROM events WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL '15 minutes';
```

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE age(now(), created_at) < '15 minutes';
```

Comment: This one can't use an index on created_at.