# Select PostgreSQL table rows younger than a week

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am creating a chatbox, and have run into a problem. I only want to select rows that were inserted into the table less than a week ago. How would I do so in PostgreSQL? My insert code is here:

```
echo $db->query_one_field("select json_build_object('max',max(chat_id),'chats',array_to_json(array_agg(z))) from (select chat_id, to_char(time,'Day HH24:MI') timee, name, text from chat where chat_id>$1 order by chat_id) z",$_GET['newfrom']);
```

I've read this: [PostgreSQL: SELECT WHERE less than 15 minutes old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044103/postgresql-select-where-less-than-15-minutes-old) but I'm not sure how to intergrate it to my code, as I am new to PHP

Comment: after `where chat_id>$1` add ` and time > now() - '1 week'::interval`

Comment: Thank you, in a week I can tell you if it worked!

Comment: Out of interest, why didn't you make that an answer?

Comment: sorry - I wasn't sure I understood you right. so first check and if it what you want I will make it answer to confirm

Comment: That is what I want, sorry I was unclear.

Comment: sure then, glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this clause to the query.

after:

```
where chat_id>$1
```

add

```
and time > now() - '1 week'::interval
```